# How can i trace related entities in debugging time in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, expression, visualization

How can i trace related entities as like an expression tree?For instance; i have foo() method.This method calls and pass various paramters to DoIt() method.Followed example may be help about my question.

```
Foo() : return type : void
 |
 +---> DoIt(param:String) : return type : void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to trace function calls with parameters and return values.